# Project structure for Django Application with multiple authentication type

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django although have done web projects using PHP/laravel. I am trying to learn Django by developing a simple project.

My project will be a sample food delivery project. There are mainly two parts.

1. Web Dashboard for Food Store Owners
2. API for Customer APP

for the Web Dashboard part, I am planning to use session-based authentication and templates. So owners/managers will register/login to the dashboard and manage orders.

and For the Customer APP, It will be some rest APIs for the Mobile APP. Customers will be able to register/login to the Mobile APP and place orders. I am planning to use JWT token for this part.

Now, I am a little bit confused about the project structure. Will I make two different apps for the Web and API part? How to manage two different types of authentication? I will be glad if someone can give me some tips and let me know the best practice for structuring this type of project.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes Django is pretty handy is this case all you have to do is use token base authentication for your rest API and you can use django native authentication for the web application. In case of web application you will simple authenticate the user and give him permission to access site but in case of the restAPI if user will authenticate then you will generate a token for it, i am writing some steps for you to follow.

1. Take a look at How Django User authentication work [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/) and how to override the user model to add you desired fields [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/)
2. Take a look at the [Django rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and [token base authentication](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/22/how-to-implement-token-authentication-using-django-rest-framework.html)